# Does the expression “en être encore à faire” always carry a negative connotation?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, connotation

> Tu **en es encore à** apprendre à faire des injections indolores ?

I said this sentence to a nursing student today to just check to see how she is coming along. But now I wonder if it might not have been taken as a criticism levelled at her slow progress? If so, I dread to think how rude I must have come across!

Here's hoping this expression can be used neutrally as well without any negative connotation...

Comment: Je ne vois pas comment on pourrait interpréter la phrase autrement que... ce qu'elle dit ! :( *encore à*... ça ne pardonne pas...

Comment: @jcm69 Ça, je m'en doutais, j'ai foiré dans les grandes largeurs !

Comment: Il te reste les bonbons ou les fleurs, ça dépend.

Comment: Probably not *that* rude, and now you have a new conversation subject, explaining away the confusion. Makes good memories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it has a negative connotation and "encore à" suggests that the student is either slow at learning or that you have learnt that long time ago and that he/she should have too (it might be interpreted as condescension).